# Could someone please delete my account? Thanks!

Tags: discussion

Could someone please delete my account? Thanks! I need help with this now, thanks

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you have initiated the account deletion process and are now waiting for the countdown to over. [This is the standard process](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account).

Note that moderators don't delete accounts by request. You have to wait until the countdown is over.